# Can ZFS subvolumes contain other filesystems?

Tags: filesystems, osx, zfs, steam

I want to format a subvolume with a filesystem other than ZFS, since a program I use needs certain File System features ZFS doesn't have (Portal 2 on macOS has File System constraints). APFS has a feature that allows a subvolume to be formatted differently than the main container, so I wonder if ZFS supports this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. [An example](http://fibrevillage.com/storage/168-zfs-pool-zfs-datasets-and-zfs-volumes) illustrates creating an [ext3](http://web.mit.edu/rhel-doc/5/RHEL-5-manual/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-ext3.html) subvolume underneath [ZFS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/zfsover-2/).

```
#mkfs -t ext3 -L lun4 /dev/zvol/zpool12_3/lun4
```